# PHP Web Service For iOS and Android

Tags: php, web-services

I am kinda new to writing web services and I just need to make a simple one in PHP. I am not getting anything returned when using curl. Can anyone suggest why? I am using MAMP as a virtual host. Here is my service code:

```
 <?php

 include_once("JSON.php");
 $json = new Services_JSON();

 $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost:8888", "root", "root") or die("Could not connect");
 mysql_select_db("Test_RMS") or die("Could not select database");

 $arr = array();

 $rs = mysql_query("Select * from RMS_Inventory");
 while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
 $arr[] = $obj;

 }

 echo $json->encode($arr);

 ?>
```

And here is what I am running for the CURL command

```
 curl http://localhost:8888/Tatyana.com/service2.php
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Should you really be trying to connect to MySQL on port 8888?  Do you really want to use persistent connections?  What response code do you get in cURL?  Have you considered using MySQL library that is not deprecated (mysqli or PDO perhaps)?

Comment: I took this example from this site: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-web-service-for-an-ios-app-part-one/ Do you have a suggestion on a good tutorial? I am not getting any response code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is crashing before print something and the error_reporting is set to 0, doesn't show nothing. Probably you need to check your error log to see what is happening.

Comment: if you are using MAMP should be in MAMP/logs/php_error.log

Comment: Is json.php in your script directory? what is the php version? So if you have php 5.2 or later you can use json_encode function without including any new library.

Comment: I ended up going the route of mysqli. And thank you for pointing me to the logs. That will help immensely in the future!